# Ignore spelling error in DocX file

Tags: ms-word, openxml

Using OpenXML, I'm inserting some text into a document that I know will be marked as incorrectly spelled (because it's a product name) and will be marked with the angry red line/squiggly when the file is opened in Word. How can I mark the XML so that it knows that the spelling is correct for that word?

I've tried messing around with [ProofError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.prooferror%28v=office.14%29.aspx), putting it in various places with relation to my paragraph and my run and with different values for type, but can't figure out if there's a way to use that to mark something as *not* an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProofError` is to actually mark the text run with the *angry red line*. To exclude the text in a run for spell/ grammar checks use `noProof`.

Lets say you got a word in a run as:

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Cfgcfgcyhgjguih</w:t>
   </w:r>
</w:p>
```

You can tell the spell/grammar checking engine of the word client to ignore this word for checks, in the run properties as below

```
<w:p>
  <w:rPr>
    <w:noProof w:val="true"/>
  </w:rPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>Cfgcfgcyhgjguih</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

You can also globally disable the spell/grammar checking engine to stop looking for errors in a document by specifying so in the documents `settings`part as:

```
<w:proofState w:spelling="clean" w:grammar="clean"/>
```

The above prevents the client's spell/grammar checking to kick-in until the next edit made to the document.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did it. Thanks. Don't know why I couldn't find that yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the SDK, you can do the following to hide all spelling errors in the entire document:

```
var hideSpellingErrors = new HideSpellingErrors();            
hideSpellingErrors.Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(true);
document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Append(hideSpellingErrors);
```

This can be useful when - as in my case - you auto-generate a document from a template where you *know* all text is correctly spelled. Plus, when the content you add dynamically come from an external source or is full of domain-specific words - like pharmaceutical terms.

Answer (score 1):

Just Added Snippet of code in c#.

creating instance of `NoProof` class and setting its value to `true`, then appending to instance of `RunProperties`

```
   NoProof np = new NoProof();
   np.Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(true);
   runProp.Append(np);
```