# When using Python docx how to enable spelling in output document?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I'm using the Python docx library to generate an document, that I would like to be able to open and find spelling errors in.  But when I open the document none of the spelling errors flag (little red underlines) or are identified if I run a spell check.  If I edit a line or copy, cut and paste the content back into word the spelling functionality works as expected.

Is there some way to get the output document to display/recognize spelling errors in the output document automatically?  I've played around with the "no_proof" flag but that doesn't seem to help.  (Using 64 bit Python 3.4, docx 8.6 on a Windows box, Opening output in Word 2013)

Thanks for any ideas!

Code to reproduce:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('This has a spellling errror')
document.save(r'SpellingTester.docx')
```

Output in Word :
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try using `document.settings` object that it's wrapping the lxml node element of the document.
As you can see from the documentation there's the `hideSpellingErrors` attribute.

[Python DOCX Settings](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/settings.html)

```
<xsd:element name="hideSpellingErrors" type="CT_OnOff" minOccurs="0"/>
```

EDIT:
After researching a little further I would try something like that:

```
import docx

document = docx.Document()

DOCX = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'

element = document.settings.element.find(DOCX + 'proofState')
element.attrib[DOCX + 'grammar'] = 'dirty'
element.attrib[DOCX + 'spelling'] = 'dirty'

document.add_paragraph("This has a spellling errror")
document.save("test.docx")
```

With `DOCX` prefix that can change, but it's easily read in the lxml element.
I don't know right now if there's a way to do things more directly and cleanly but this works for me.

More about `proofState` setting in docx:

- [Same problem here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1209)
- [Trying to do the opposite here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549842/ignore-spelling-error-in-docx-file)

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thank you.

Comment: Use nsmap to help futureproof the code:
`nsmap = document.settings.element.nsmap;
proofstate = document.settings.element.find("w:proofState", nsmap);
proofstate.set("{{{}}}grammar".format(nsmap["w"]), "dirty");
proofstate.set("{{{}}}spelling".format(nsmap["w"]), "dirty")`